# how to enable virtualization in BIOS settings

Tags: bios, virtualization

I am not able to find virtualization option in my BIOS settings

Processor Info : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E7500  @ 2.93GHz, 2926 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 2 Logical Processor(s)

BIOS Version Info: Intel Corp. RQG4110H.86A.0013.2009.1223.1136

My system is running windows7 and I checked with the detector that my system supports virtualization just it is not enabled.Please help and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your motherboard and/or BIOS may not fully support your processor and thus is not providing an option for enabling virtualization. You might try updating your BIOS.

The E7500 comes in two flavors, SLGTE (R0, with VT) and SLB9Z (R0). One with virtualization support and one without. Check your Processor Spec Number. Should be on the box the processor came in and on the processor itself.

You might also try an alternate application to detect for virtualization, for example SecurAble. Checking the processor directly is the best option though.

Comment: @payalagrawal: Great! You might accept the answer, it's helpful to others to signify that the answer provided a solution to the question or was useful in addressing the question.